# How to properly use the print function

Tags: python

```
while index < len(diecount):
    print(index)
    for number in range(diecount[index]):
        print('*')

    index+=1
    print("")
```

At the moment i am getting

```
1
**
2
3
**
```

i want the output to be

```
1 **
2
3 **
```

Comment: A tip: You can discard those redundant brackets.     while index < len(diecount):                                                                          It's Python ,no need for C style.

Comment: The parentheses are required in Python 3.x, as `print` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: @chepner : look at the edit history and the content of the comment

Comment: Ah, those redundant parentheses.

Comment: @DamnDev: Actually, those parentheses aren't even C style. (C style would be `while (index < len(diecount))`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more Pythonic way to write this:

```
for index, count in enumerate(diecount[1:], start=1):
    print(index, '*' * count)
```

(Manually controlling loop indexes in a `while` is usually a sign you're trying to write C code in Python).

Comment: i agree. but while using this code i changed the start to 0  because when at 1 the '*' was not on the same line it was meant to be.
how can i code it in such a way that i want it to display the output from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @user2775042: what does the `diecount` object look like that you want to produce the output you show?

Comment: diecount is a list
it is diecount[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} which gets updated everytime a value is returned for example if i get 1 and 2, the list would change to [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: But in your example do you have `[0, 2, 0, 2]` or `[2, 0, 2]`?

Comment: Well I'll be. `enumerate` grew a `start` parameter in 2.6 while I wasn't looking. I wonder how much code I've written with unnecessary `+ 1` or `+ offset`. To make myself feel better, I'm going to just say that I was designing for backward compatibility. Yeah. (Actually, there's no mention of it in the "What's New for 2.6", so that also makes me feel a little better. A little.)

Answer (score 4):

Each print function appends a newline at the end of whatever it currently prints.
You can append a space instead of newline after the first print using the 2nd argument:

```
print(index, end = " ")
```

Comment: thanks for that.but when i append the end="", the numbers which doesn't have the ** gets written in the same line.

Comment: You'll need to not use them there then; or use a `print()` call with no arguments to print a newline.

Comment: if i use  a print("") with nothing i get the same output as before